# MVC best practice for create/confirm/persist process

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony

I have an addAction like this:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $object = new Object();
    $object->setAttrib('foo');

    if($object->isValid())
    {
        $session->set('_object', $object);
        return $this->redirect('confirmAction');
    }
}
```

and in the confirmAction:

```
public function confirmAction($confirm = 'not_confirmed')
{
    if($confirm == 'confirm')
    {
        $object = $session->get('_object');
        if($object->isValid())
        {
            $entityManager->persist($object);
            $session->remove('_object');
            return $this->redirect('listAction');
        }
    }

    $this->renderTemplate('with confirm link');
}
```

I dont like the $session->set part. What is the best practice for this create/confirm/persist things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should ask yourself whether or not you want to use JavaScript. A confirmation box would be in my opinion the most sensible solution, since the client doesn't make another round-trip to the server.

If for some reason you don't want to use JavaScript, your method is the way to go. Instead of using `$session->set('...');`, you could use `$session->setFlash('...')`, which will store the value in the session for only one request and deletes it afterward.

If a user decides not to confirm the action, you could use `$session->setFlash('...')` yet again to display the previous state of a form. Using this method is better, because you won't be having any leftover session values just hanging there.